# Xcart classic - Products randomly appearing disappearing from the cart

Tags: x-cart

I am using xcart classic 4.7.1 for my shop. We did a lot of customization in the code to make it suitable for my clients need. We made it live the previous year and everything worked fine. Now, these days a strange issue is happening. The products are randomly appearing and disappearing in the cart. Sometimes after adding the products to cart, the cart stays empty. It is not happening regularly. Sometimes if a product is deleted from the cart, previous products are randomly added into the cart again. Suppose the cart containing 4 products. Customer deleting the products one by one. After he deleted the last product, previously deleted products are showing in the cart again. As it is not happening regularly, it is very hard to track it and fix it. A lot of customers are complaining and my client is not happy now.

Thank you very much in advance. Blessings.

Answer (score 0):

1)Try to convert the engine type from MyISAM to InnoDB for the xcart_sessions_data table.

For this

run the query

```
ALTER TABLE xcart_sessions_data ENGINE=INNODB;
```

2)Maybe upgrade to the newest X-Cart version will fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe upgrade to the newest X-Cart version will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since there has been a lot of customization in your cart, as you wrote, the most probable reason is some bug in the customizations, related to the cart functionality. Have you had any customizations on the cart functionality itself?